# (How) can I set session data from inside a django test?

Tags: python, django, session

I'm relying on some session data for my django tests.
I was wondering if i could still do that or if i need to rethink my logic.

Anyway, i'm trying to set the session data like this:

```
self.client.session['last_page_id'] = unicode(self.t1_p5.id)

response = self.client.post(final_page_path, final_page_answers,
                                    follow=True)
```

So not only is the `self.client.session` attribute an "empty" after the assignment, but also my session is actually empty at the time it is being used - and yes the value assigned does indeed exist - no `AttributeError` is raised.

**[EDIT]**
django version 1.6

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which version of Django you use but in some old docs it is written:

> To modify the session and then save it, it must be stored in a variable first (because a new SessionStore is created every time this property is accessed):

Example:

```
def test_something(self):
    session = self.client.session
    session['somekey'] = 'test'
    session.save()
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.session)

Comment: actually the `session` attribute is a dict in my case, not at all an instance of say `SessionStore` - so it doesn't even have a `.save` method. This doesn't work :| updated the question - thx for the answer